# UIStackView() vs UIStackView(frame: .zero) initialiser

Tags: ios

I would like to ask about the difference between UIStackView() and UIStackView(frame: .zero) initialisers.

I would like to know which one of the two is triggered by UIStackView() by default.

```
@interface UIStackView : UIView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference, the `convenience` `UIView` initializer without parameters calls `UIView(frame: .zero)`.

The `init(coder:)` initializer is used only when the view is decoded from a xib/storyboard.